# Memory read access violation when using Triangle mesh generation library in C++ project

Tags: c++, c, triangle

I'm trying to use J. Shewchuk's mesh generation library Triangle in a C++ program. To do this I first downloaded triangle.h and triangle.c from the Triangle website. Then, in triangle.c I included these defines

```
#define NO_TIMER
#define TRILIBRARY
#define ANSI_DECLARATORS
```

I then compiled this into a library file, Triangle.lib, and put this in my C++ project's lib folder (and linked to it). I also copied triangle.h into my project's include folder and modified it to be wrapped with `extern "C"`. With this my project compiles fine and can use the functions from triangle.h.

I then copied the example found in tricall.h into my project as follows:

```
#define REAL double

struct triangulateio in, mid, out, vorout;

in.numberofpoints = 4;
in.numberofpointattributes = 1;
in.pointlist = (REAL*)malloc(in.numberofpoints * 2 * sizeof(REAL));
in.pointlist[0] = 0.0;
in.pointlist[1] = 0.0;
in.pointlist[2] = 1.0;
in.pointlist[3] = 0.0;
in.pointlist[4] = 1.0;
in.pointlist[5] = 10.0;
in.pointlist[6] = 0.0;
in.pointlist[7] = 10.0;
in.pointattributelist = (REAL*)malloc(in.numberofpoints * in.numberofpointattributes * sizeof(REAL));
in.pointattributelist[0] = 0.0;
in.pointattributelist[1] = 1.0;
in.pointattributelist[2] = 11.0;
in.pointattributelist[3] = 10.0;
in.pointmarkerlist = (int*)malloc(in.numberofpoints * sizeof(int));
in.pointmarkerlist[0] = 0;
in.pointmarkerlist[1] = 2;
in.pointmarkerlist[2] = 0;
in.pointmarkerlist[3] = 0;

in.numberofsegments = 0;
in.numberofholes = 0;
in.numberofregions = 1;
in.regionlist = (REAL*)malloc(in.numberofregions * 4 * sizeof(REAL));
in.regionlist[0] = 0.5;
in.regionlist[1] = 5.0;
in.regionlist[2] = 7.0;
in.regionlist[3] = 0.1;

    /* Make necessary initializations so that Triangle can return a */
    /*   triangulation in `mid' and a voronoi diagram in `vorout'.  */

mid.pointlist = (REAL*)NULL;            /* Not needed if -N switch used. */
mid.pointattributelist = (REAL*)NULL;
mid.pointmarkerlist = (int*)NULL; /* Not needed if -N or -B switch used. */
mid.trianglelist = (int*)NULL;          /* Not needed if -E switch used. */
mid.triangleattributelist = (REAL*)NULL;
mid.neighborlist = (int*)NULL;         /* Needed only if -n switch used. */
mid.segmentlist = (int*)NULL;
mid.segmentmarkerlist = (int*)NULL;
mid.edgelist = (int*)NULL;             /* Needed only if -e switch used. */
mid.edgemarkerlist = (int*)NULL;   /* Needed if -e used and -B not used. */

vorout.pointlist = (REAL*)NULL;        /* Needed only if -v switch used. */
vorout.pointattributelist = (REAL*)NULL;
vorout.edgelist = (int*)NULL;          /* Needed only if -v switch used. */
vorout.normlist = (REAL*)NULL;         /* Needed only if -v switch used. */                                        

triangulate(const_cast<char*>("pczAevn"), &in, &mid, &vorout);
```

However, I get an error on the last line where I call triangulate. The error is "Exception thrown: write access violation. vertexloop was 0x8E064FF0", and comes from line 14130 in triangle.c

```
x = vertexloop[0] = pointlist[coordindex++];
```

Any idea why this error is occurring? Is my approach to including the C code in my C++ program the right way to do so?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include that here. Doing so, also remove the "c" tag, because this isn't about C code. Also, try to step through the code with a debugger, I'm sure you'll quickly find out what's going on. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Personally I would use `std::vector` not `malloc` (this is a C++ program after all). But otherwise your code seems to be correct. But I have no knowledge of this library, and either your code or the library could be bugged.

Comment: ```malloc``` in not ```C++```. Either use ```std::malloc``` or ```new```. Better would be to use ```std::unique_ptr<REAL>``` if possible.

Comment: I know nothing about the library, but the `const_cast<char *>("pczAevn")` in the call of `triangulate()` has a certain stench to it.   `"pczAevn"` is a string literal, and modifying a string literal gives undefined behaviour.   The `const_cast` allows (in the sense of forcing a compiler to not diagnose an attempt) `triangulate()` to modify characters in that literal.   If the function is modifying data pointed to by its first argument, that might explain your error.

Comment: The code in my question comes directly from the library, which is written in C, hence the use of `malloc`. The `const_cast` isn't ideal, but it was just to keep the code as similar as possible to the library code. I've checked and it's not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I've found a C++ version of the code on Github by libigl
https://github.com/libigl/triangle. As before, need to include:

```
#define NO_TIMER
#define TRILIBRARY
#define ANSI_DECLARATORS
```

In `triangle.cpp`. Also now including the source files directly in my project instead of compiling to a separate library. With this, no longer get the memory read address error. Looking at the difference between `triangle.cpp` and `triangle.c` libigl has added this line:

```
/* Define the size large enough to store and operate on a pointer. */
#define INT_PTR unsigned long long
```

And everywhere in `triangle.c` that previously had a pointer to `unsigned long` has been replaced with `INT_PTR`. I suspect this has fixed what was initially causing the error.